# Nested Viewpager Fragment not getting initialized

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, navigation-drawer

I have 3 `fragments part of a navigation drawer`, one of which contains a viewpager. When I first load the app, the viewpager loads all the fragments. However, when I switch to another fragment using the navi-drawer and I switch back, one of the viewpager fragments is not loading. I have tried the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125594/navigation-drawer-viewpager-fragments-viewpager-doesnt-destroy-nested-frag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699022/viewpager-fragments-fragment-not-shown) but I'm not able to come up with a solution.

In my pageradapter code, in the switch case for different fragments; I have put a log for the position, and position 1 does not seem to be coming after the initial load of the app.

My question is, why is it that position 1 never gets called? Can someone explain it to me?

Here's my Pageradapter code:

```
 class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

static HeartRate_Fragment heartRate_fragment;
static Calorie_Fragment calorie_fragment;
static  Steps_Fragment steps_fragment;

int num;
public PagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //add new fragment here for homepage viewpager
    Log.d("position",position+"");
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
           if(calorie_fragment == null)
            calorie_fragment = new Calorie_Fragment();
           Log.d("flip",0+"");
            return calorie_fragment;

        case 1:
            if(heartRate_fragment == null)
                heartRate_fragment = new HeartRate_Fragment();
            Log.d("flip",1+"");
            return heartRate_fragment;


        case 2:
            if(steps_fragment == null)
            steps_fragment = new Steps_Fragment();
            Log.d("flip",2+"");
            return steps_fragment;


        default:
            return null;

    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return num;
}

public HeartRate_Fragment getHRFragment()
{
    return heartRate_fragment;
}
public Calorie_Fragment getCalorie_fragment()
{
    return calorie_fragment;
}
public  Steps_Fragment getSteps_fragment()
{
    return steps_fragment;
}
```

Comment: you wanna open second fragment on swipe ?

Comment: My homefragment already contains a viewpager. That viewpager contains 3 fragments. In that, the 2nd one is not getting initialized. The first and third are.

Comment: How are you checking it ?

Comment: I can see it not being initialized. Its a graph. And I dont see the graph.

Comment: Ok. that fragment has graph. Can you post more code so we can get any mistake ?

Comment: Can we make this a private conversation? Stackoverflow doesn't like it if we have a conversation through comments. I can send you my entire code through a zip.

Comment: can you post some more code to get the idea where you do mistake..

Comment: Your fragment which contains viewpager should called it's child fragment with getChildFragmentManager() if you not doing this you face unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I tried getChildFragmentManager(), that doesn't resolve the issue. It pops up a "cannot resolve method getChildFragmentmanager()" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

static HeartRate_Fragment heartRate_fragment;
static Calorie_Fragment calorie_fragment;
static  Steps_Fragment steps_fragment;

int num;
public PagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);

}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  //add new fragment here for homepage viewpager
Log.d("position",position+"");
switch (position) {

    case 0:

        if(calorie_fragment == null){
        calorie_fragment = new Calorie_Fragment();
        return calorie_fragment;
        }else {
         return getCalorie_fragment(); }         

    case 1:
        if(heartRate_fragment == null){
            heartRate_fragment = new HeartRate_Fragment();
            return heartRate_fragment;}
         else{ return getHRFragment();}

    case 2:
        if(steps_fragment == null){
        steps_fragment = new Steps_Fragment();
        return steps_fragment;
        }
        else{ return getSteps_fragment();} 

    default:
        return null;

}

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return 3;
}

 public HeartRate_Fragment getHRFragment()
  {
  return heartRate_fragment;
  }
  public Calorie_Fragment getCalorie_fragment()
  {
  return calorie_fragment;
  }
  public  Steps_Fragment getSteps_fragment()
  {
  return steps_fragment;
  }
```

try this make sure you are using `getChildFragmentManager();`

Comment: note: default of **setOffscreenPageLimit** is 3 and you dont need to set it explicitly.

Comment: I can't use getChildFragmentManager(), in my homefragment code, when I call  pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getChildFragmentManager(),3); it throws up cannot resolve method getChildFragmentmanager

Comment: @RicheekDey use pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); like this inside your fragment

Comment: Okay now nothing is coming. :/ the viewpager is blank now from the first time I load the app.

Comment: in get count you are returning num where you give value to this variable

Comment: Yes, so? I'm saying right now the viewpager is not even loading any fragment. I'll show you, one sec

Comment: try this `@Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
   }`make your get count return 3

Comment: This has worked like charm: Simply change from 
    getActivity().getFragmentManager() to getChildFragmentmanager()